# How do I save word cloud as .png in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a word cloud based on a string and then importing it into a report document. I am using python-docx, matplotlib, and word cloud. 
This is a brief summary of my

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document()
document.add_heading("Auto Generated Report")

text = "kd sa gf sdf gd python auomation get set python dfs aslkdf asdfij fdifh fdosfj dsfoj "

cloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.title('Summarization of responses on possible improvements of CS course.')
plt.savefig('N.png')

document.add_picture('N.png', width=Inches(5))

document.save("Report")
```

However, instead of displaying a word cloud, the report just shows a blank graph.

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be with matplotlib? If not, you can just `cloud = 
cloud.to_file('N.png')`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Supplemental to @Andy's answer, `cloud.to_file('N.png')` is how you save the word cloud image into your local disk so that you can import later. You can find a good reference [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python).

Comment: This seems to give images in low resolution & size. How can I save it in HD format?