# How to create wordcloud chart for each userid based on frequency and value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, word-cloud

Im trying to create each word cloud graph for each user based on the word and count frequency and I want to store output of word cloud image path in dataframe along with UID.Do I need apply group by? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
|UID         |word                     |count          
=================================================
|ccf878ec9315|RT                       |28               
|ccf878ec9315|Newpin                   |6                
|ccf878ec9315|Benefit Bond             |6                
|ccf878ec9315|Covid                    |5                
|ccf878ec9315|Blues                    |5                
|ccf878ec9316|TPG                      |10               
|ccf878ec9316|Learn                    |8                
|ccf878ec9316|An                       |6                
|ccf878ec9317|GIINs Market Roadmap     |9                
|ccf878ec9317|amp                      |5                
|ccf878ec9317|Varsity                  |3                
|ccf878ec9318|International Womens Day |10               
|ccf878ec9318|Solving                  |8                
|ccf878ec9318|Hadewych                 |4                
|ccf878ec9319|GIF16                    |4               
|ccf878ec9319|Kuyper                   |9                
|ccf878ec9320|Impact Investments       |8                
|ccf878ec9320|Climate                  |3
```

I tried with frequency count which is having all the data for entire dataset. But Im unable to create word cloud graph for each UID.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=200).generate_from_frequencies(data)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`data`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html) in `generate_from_frequencies(data)` needs to be a Python dictionary similar to `{'RT': 28, 'Newpin': 6, 'Benefit Bond': 6, 'Covid': 5, ...}`.
Here is an approach to create such a dictionary from the given dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'UID': ['ccf878ec9315', 'ccf878ec9315', 'ccf878ec9315', 'ccf878ec9315', 'ccf878ec9315',
                           'ccf878ec9316', 'ccf878ec9316', 'ccf878ec9316', 'ccf878ec9317', 'ccf878ec9317',
                           'ccf878ec9317', 'ccf878ec9318', 'ccf878ec9318', 'ccf878ec9318', 'ccf878ec9319',
                           'ccf878ec9319', 'ccf878ec9320', 'ccf878ec9320'],
                   'word': ['RT', 'Newpin', 'Benefit Bond', 'Covid', 'Blues', 'TPG', 'Learn', 'An',
                            'GIINs Market Roadmap', 'amp', 'Varsity', 'International Womens Day', 'Solving', 'Hadewych',
                            'GIF16', 'Kuyper', 'Impact Investments', 'Climate'],
                   'count': [28, 6, 6, 5, 5, 10, 8, 6, 9, 5, 3, 10, 8, 4, 4, 9, 8, 3]})
data = {wrd: cnt for wrd, cnt in zip(df['word'], df['count'])}

from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=200).generate_from_frequencies(data)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Alternatively, to create the dictionary fully within pandas:

```py
data = df.set_index('word')['count'].to_dict()
```

To create a wordcloud per UID:

```py
uids = np.unique(df['UID'])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=(len(uids)+2)//3, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 8),
                         gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.05, 'wspace': 0.05, 'left': 0.01, 'right': 0.99, 'top': 0.99, 'bottom': 0.01})for uid, ax in zip(uids, axes.ravel()):
    data = df[df['UID'] == uid].set_index('word')['count'].to_dict()

    wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=200).generate_from_frequencies(data)
    ax.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
    ax.set_title(f'UID = {uid}')
    ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: all UIDs]

Comment: Thank you. But how can we apply it based on the UID?

Comment: Does the updated answer work for you? Also [How do I save word cloud as .png in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464932/how-do-i-save-word-cloud-as-png-in-python) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Johan you saved my time